# Onenote macro language command

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

I am looking for a way to either remove whole page using one note macro, or clear content of a specific page. 
This is for a macro that will create summary page. Right now my macro creates new summary page every time. I would like to keep one page and keep "rebuilding" it with that macro, so I need to either remove or wipe old one. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what macro language you are using. If you are willing to dig into C# code, you can code up using the OneNote REST API.  http://dev.onenote.com.  Those operations you are talking about (updating/patching an existing page, or deleting/creating a new page) are possible.